# Proving an inequality with geometric mean

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, information-theory

I'm interested by the following problem :

> Let $x,y,z>0$ such that $x\geq y \geq z$ and $x-y=y-z=0.5(x-z)$ then we have :
>   $$f(x,y,z)=\Big(x^xy^yz^z\Big)^{\frac{1}{x+y+z}}+(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq x+z$$

Since it's homogeneous we have :
$$f(\alpha x , \alpha y , \alpha z)=\alpha f(x,y,z)$$
We put $\alpha=\frac{1}{y}$ and $u=\frac{x}{y}$ and $v=\frac{z}{y}$ we get :
$$f(x,y,z)=yf(u,1,v)\leq y(u+v)$$
and the condition is equivalent to $u+v=2$ so we have the following equivalent for $1\leq v \leq 2$ :
$$\Big(v^v(2-v)^{(2-v)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}+(v(2-v))^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq 2$$

Wich is true graphically otherwise I try power series but it's too boring and derivatives also .

We can generalize this easily but it's an other subject .

I think futhermore that there is consequences in information theory .

My question is :

How to prove it elegantly ?

Edit : the link with Information theory :

The inequality is equivalent to :

$$\Big(x^xy^yz^z\Big)^{\frac{1}{x+y+z}}+y+(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq x+y+z$$

Or if we divide by $x+y+z$ :

$$\Big((\frac{x}{x+y+z})^{\frac{x}{x+y+z}}(\frac{y}{x+y+z})^{\frac{y}{x+y+z}}(\frac{z}{x+y+z})^{\frac{z}{x+y+z}}\Big)+(\frac{y}{x+y+z})+(\frac{x}{x+y+z}\frac{y}{x+y+z}\frac{z}{x+y+z})^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq 1$$

So if we put $a=\frac{x}{x+y+z}$ and $b=\frac{y}{x+y+z}$ and $c=\frac{z}{x+y+z}$ we get :

> $$a^ab^bc^c+b+(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq 1$$
>   With $a+b+c=1$ and $2b=a+c$

Or :
$$a^ab^bc^c\leq 1-b-(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
If we take the log on both side we have :

$$a\log(a)+b\log(b)+c\log(c)\leq \log(1-b-(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}})$$

Wich is in link with Shannon's entropy .

Many thanks

Comment: What is the connection to information theory?

Comment: You might gain some attention if you change the title ("Prove inequality" or something like that), and remove the Information Theory thing (or leave as an aside... but with some explanation).  You might also explain with more detail how you reduce the first inequality to the second one.